# Javascript Collection Framework

Tags: java, javascript, collections

Like Java having its Collection Framework .
Is there any api available in `Javascript` where

we can Store JSON object in map for key value pair and

it will be having sort functionality and

List or Vector functionality where the size will be auto growable and

HashSet/TreeSet functionality to store duplicate free Json Object or item.

**EDIT:**

ListI terator functionality will be there where we can traverse bi-directionally.

One More functionality it lacking is removal of item from middle of array can be    achieved so that it will rearrange after.

Comparator facity will be a added advantage.

Answer (score 4):

No. Most of these features are native to JavaScript.

- every javascript Object is just key-value pairs (and, mostly, a prototype...) - you know  **J**ava**S**cript**O**bject**N**otation?
- Lists and Vectors are all covered by the native Array type which auto-grows
- All Arrays inherit the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, with custom comparator methods available
- ... and you won't need long to find a snippet that removes duplicates from Objects/Arrays. Even with custom comparators.
- (the edited): All Arrays inherit the [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove items from indizes
- ListIterators: As of ES5.1, all Arrays have [iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) which work great with JavaScript's functional approach

Yet, there are some libraries to extend these features. E.g. underscore.js treats Objects and Arrays both as iterable collections, there exist HashMap implementations for storing values by non-string-keys etc etc. Also, nearly all of the MVC frameworks implement their own collection objects (for models) to keep up with changes on them.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented `HashTable` with arbitrary keys and `HashSet` in my [jshashtable](http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's built-in array is 'auto-growable', and is actually pretty similar to the functionality you'd get from Collection in Java.

If however you need something like a HashSet, you could take a look at [TaffyDB](http://taffydb.com/), which is supposed to be a "database" of sorts for Javascript, but I think it works in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJs (definitely) and (I think) jQuery have such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at Backbone JS I think you can use its models and collections.
Web site http://backbonejs.org/ and tutorials here http://backbonetutorials.com/

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library mentioned below. Just do `npm install collectiondatalib`.

**Features**: [www.npmjs.com/package/collectiondatalib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/collectiondatalib)

It is really easy to use and all collections- searching- and sorting-methods are available.